# collectstatic not reading settings file using git push heroku master but reads it when run on its own

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

If I enter

```
>>> git push heroku master
```

I get an error. Notice line 25 stating that I have not set the `STATIC_ROOT` setting.

```
1  remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
2  remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
3  remote:          File "manage.py", line 22, in 
4  remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
5  remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
6  remote:            utility.execute()
7  remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
8  remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
9  remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
10 remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
11 remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
12 remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
13 remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 199, in handle
14 remote:            collected = self.collect()
15 remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 124, in collect
16 remote:            handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
17 remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 354, in copy_file
18 remote:            if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage)
19 remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 260, in delete_file
20 remote:            if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
21 remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 392, in exists
22 remote:            return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
23 remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 50, in path
24 remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
25 remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
26 remote: 
27 remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'
28 remote:        See traceback above for details.
```

My settings file includes these values

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In addition, if I enter `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` it runs fine.

Comment: Are you pushing your settings file?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would you check that? It is part of the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked github. It turns out my settings file was not in sync with my local settings file. Meaning the settings file on github didn't have `STATIC_ROOT` set. I just

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Added files and changes required for `deployment to heroku"
git push origin master
```

Which updated my settings file on github. Then

```
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

It worked. I don't know if this is helpful. If someone downvotes, I'll delete this question.